# Http response code on demand

Tags: http, request, response

I need to test the behavior of the app I'm developing in front of different http response codes. Do you know any site or program that returns an http response with the http code that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to have understood what you need... Maybe you can try this:
http://www.gethttpstatuscode.com/